# Reasons for different tooltips implementations in the user summary page

Tags: discussion, profile-page, tooltips

The [summary tab page in an user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=summary) currently is split into three main areas/lists of posts: the question area, the answer area and the reputation area.

[image: Cthul... I mean, Shog9's Profile]

Yet, for some reason, only the answers and questions lists define tooltips on the links items. The items in the reputation area are left without any tooltip.
Also worth notice that if we have a look at more *determined* users like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/286591/dj-mcmayhem?tab=summary)
[image]
[image]

one may notice that while the links contains additional question metadata like the [closed], [duplicate] and so on statuses, the tooltips don't share such love. This make them especially useless in situations where the question name is too long (second question in the screenshot above) and so the "metadata" status info is cut off in the link.

Is there any special reason for this behavior, like increased page build cost on the server side? Or is this simply something that slipped in and no one noticed?

(PS: I am marking this as discussion for now, since I don't know yet if a feature request is appropriate. As now, I would like to know if extending the tooltip with the metadatas would be doable without too much effort)